# How do I randomly merge two input files to one output file using unix tools?

Tags: linux, unix

I have two text files, of different sizes, which I would like to merge into one file, but with the content mixed randomly; this is to create some realistic data for some unit tests. One text file contains the true cases, while the other the false.

I would like to use standard Unix tools to create the merged output. How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Random sort using `-R`:

```bsh
$ sort -R file1 file2 -o file3
```

Comment: The result can be unexpected if the same line occurs for several times. Try `sort -R <(seq 1 10) <(seq 1 10)`.

Comment: @sudo_O I'm just letting you know that the `-R` option doesn't exist in the Mac version of `sort`.

Answer (score 3):

My version of `sort` also does not support `-R`. So here is an alternative using `awk` by inserting a random number in front of each line and sorting according to those numbers, then strip off the number.

```
awk '{print int(rand()*1000), $0}' file1 file2 | sort -n | awk '{$1="";print $0}'
```

Answer (score 0):

This adds a random number to the beginning of each line with `awk`, sorts based on that number, and then removes it. This will even work if you have duplicates (as pointed out by choroba) and is slightly more cross platform.

```
awk 'BEGIN { srand() } { print rand(), $0 }' file1 file2 |
    sort -n |
    cut -f2- -d" "
```

Comment: [UUoC](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html) and fails for all files containing more than one word per line.